# How Laravel 5 Authentication work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel 5.1 with the default Authentication system. It works pretty, but i added many fields to my User model. Now i will extent the Validation method.

Now my Question, what is this: "App/Service/Registrar.php" is it a Service Provider? Why are the default Validation in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Registrar** class in **Laravel 5.0** was a class used by **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers** to validate and create newly registered users. It was a place where you'd define your validation rules (if different from the default ones) and any additional actions that you might need to do on user creation.

This class was removed in **Laravel 5.1**. If you want to make use of **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers** or **RedirectsUsers** traits in your controller, you'll need to implement **create** and **validate** methods there.